# Using roxygen2 outside RStudio project

Tags: r, rstudio, project-template, roxygen2

I am trying to generate roxygen2 comments inside my R code and I am currently NOT using an R Project but rather using ProjectTemplate (http://projecttemplate.net/).

My problem is roxygen2 only seems to work within a Project (hopefully I am wrong about this) and therefore when I run the command

```
roxygenize('.')
```

I just get errors about a missing `DESCRIPTION` file. If I create a `DESCRIPTION` file and run 
`roxygenize('.')` again, the code executes and a `/man` and `/inst` folder is created but is blank.

Can someone please tell me if it is even possible to use roxygen2 outside of an R Project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`roxygen2` is for making help files for an R *package*.  I'm not sure how help files outside of a package context would be organised.  Would you still want R and man directories?  If so, then you are almost there with creating a package.

So, no, you can't use `roxygen2` in a not-a-package.